# Flutter Scrollable ListView get Top Value of all Items

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Flutter 2 and having a ListView builder where Widgets are built like you see in the attached screenshot.

In Top I have a horizontally scrollable menu where all categories are listed.

My goal is, that I want to know which item in the vertically scrollable ListView has which Top Value (location), so that I can estimate with the ScrollController which Catetgory is currently visible (and can be highlighted in the menu in the top - like here 'Category 1').

Hope you get my point.

I want to render all the List and have all the top values of the blue category boxes (plus height if possible).

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: If I can get you correctly; you want to know which element in the list occupies the top position right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [visibility_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector) package to detect when a widget appears in the device's viewport.

Another package you should look into should be the in [view_notifier_list](https://pub.dev/packages/inview_notifier_list) package. It should solve it

Comment: This is a good idea, the question for me is:   If I wrap each List Item in an own VisiblityDetector and they throw on each change. What if I see 3 or 4 different Items on one page... How do I know which one is the desired one (I want the top most to be responsible for the headline highlighting)?

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide another package to solve your issue and I think that should do it.

Comment: Great, yes the view_notifier_list is exactly what I was looking for!